# Access Web Application running on host on Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Web Application running on my host at port 8082 (localhost:8082). I want to access this web application through my docker container.

A quick check by installing wget on my container and running `wget localhost:8082` , I got -

```
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8082... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8082... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Is there some configuration I need to do so that my container can access the app running on my host?

PS - Localhost is Linux (CentOS)

Comment: you have to add the IP of your host as an extra host to the container (mapped to a name). Then from inside the container you can ping the host using the name you provided in the mapping.

Comment: @Mihai how Do i do that?

Comment: First find out the IP of your host (ip addr show OR ifconfig) and then change your docker command: docker run --add-host myhost=<ip from before> .... Then from inside the host you can run: ping myhost